# How can I get rid of the alpha channel in a Metal MTLTexture?

Tags: macos, textures, metal

In my Metal game, I have noticed that none of the textures have any transparent pixels, yet the alpha channel still exists. They are all redundantly filled with `0xFF` bytes.

```
let TextureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
TextureDescriptor.pixelFormat = View.colorPixelFormat
TextureDescriptor.width = 16
TextureDescriptor.height = 16
TextureDescriptor.mipmapLevelCount = 5
TextureDescriptor.textureType = MTLTextureType.type2DArray
TextureDescriptor.arrayLength = 22
TerrainTextures = Device.makeTexture(descriptor: TextureDescriptor)
// Load Textures
```

`View` is a global variable defined as as the `NSViewController` `view` cast to `MTKView`. If I try anything other than `view.colorPixelFormat`, I get issues such as discolored textures, or even nothing at all being rendered. But this happens to be `bgra8Unorm_srgb`, which *includes* alpha. I would like to cut out one quarter of texture memory by simply dropping the alpha channel for textures that do not have it. But how do I do that? How can I specify an RGB format with 3 bytes per pixel without an alpha? Then I can make the fragment shader to give an alpha channel instead of the texture coming with one? I took a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlpixelformat) and there seem to be no 24 bit formats, so is there some way to do it? Can I somehow specify a custom format instead of one of the default formats? Or will I have to simulate this by some stretch such as having 3 textures per texture, because I would be using 1 8 bit per pixel texture for each of the three RGB channels of the each complete texture?

Comment: Have you tried using a compressed texture?

Comment: @HamidYusifli How do those work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> How can I specify an RGB format with 3 bytes per pixel without an alpha?

There are no texture formats that fit your description. There are packed 32-bit formats that make use of greater precision, but there are no formats that have 8 bits per channel and fit into 24 bit, because these 24 bit formats don't fit well with modern hardware anyway.

> Can I somehow specify a custom format instead of one of the default formats?

Not really, textures are handled by a hardware unit called TPU and you can't really come up with your own texture format

> I would be using 1 8 bit per pixel texture for each of the three RGB channels of the each complete texture?

I would strongly recommend against that, because there is actually a texture cache and if you are sampling three different textures at the same texture coordinates, it doesn't know how to correlate them and you will end up with a performance hit.

Instead, you have three options.

First option is kinda hard to do cause you need a lot of infrastructure. You can either use compressed formats like ASTC or BCn. To learn more about that, there's an upcomming talk in this years [WWDC2021](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/sessions/) called Discover Metal debugging, profiling, and asset creation tools that will post on Wednesday.

Second option is to use a spare channel for some useful information, like occlusion, or some sort of mask, or anything domain-specific to your game.

Third option is just to use 32-bit formats with 8 bits per channel and just ignore the alpha or populate it with 0 or 1 as you wish. This is the easiest option and I would recommend going with it before advancing to other options.

Comment: What is with sizes needing to be power of 2 and at least 8 bits, instead of just multiple of 8 bits?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be 8 bits per channel, there are packed formats like `r5g6b5a1` and others. But not having 24-bit formats makes it easier to deal with aligned reads I would guess.

Comment: What if you were to just use buffers instead of textures, and 'sample' them manually? Then to get a color chanel at an index, you would use `byte[3*index+(0 for red, 1 for green, 2 for blue)]`